# How add dynamically a list form one object to another?

Tags: c#

I have a class that contains a list. I want to copy that list to another object that contains the same type and amount of attributes.

```
        List<CinemaUnitSchema> cinemaUnitSchemas = new List<CinemaUnitSchema>();
        foreach (CinemaUnit cinemaUnits in scenario.CinemaUnits)
        {
            cinemaUnitSchemas.Add(new CinemaUnitSchema
            {
                Name = cinemaUnits.Name,
                AttendantPoints = cinemaUnits.AttendantPoints,
                ShowPoints = cinemaUnits.ShowPoints
            });                

        }
        scenarioSchema.CinemaUnits.AddRange(CinemaUnitSchemas);
```

However, I'm receiving an error in this line of code;

```
AttendantPoints = cinemaUnits.AttendantPoints
```

The error I'm receiving is:

*"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List < MyApp.Models.AttendantPoint >' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List < MyApp.Schemas.AttendantPointSchema >'."*

Class of CinemaUnit is:

```
public class CinemaUnit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public List<AttendantPoint> AttendantPoints { get; set; }
    public bool ShowPoints { get; set; }
}
```

The Class of CinemaUnitSchema is:

```
public class CinemaUnitSchema
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public List<AttendantPoint> AttendantPoints { get; set; }
    public bool ShowPoints { get; set; }
}
```

**Solution Intended**

Add in each iteration the respective list to the new object.

Thanks,

Comment: `scenarioSchema.CinemaUnits.AddRange(CinemaUnitSchemas);` - you trying add list of one type to list of different type

Comment: And how do I fix it?

Comment: Both list will contain exactly the same amount of data, it's literally a copy of the list.

Comment: You cannot add objects of different types in same collection. This a benefit of strong typed languages (c#)

Comment: I'm creating a copy of a class, and naming it differently. There must be a way. See the classes? They contain same attributes.

Comment: "Duck typing" not supported in c#.

Comment: Containing the same attributes doesnt overshadow the fact that they are different types. You need to copy over all properties from one object to the new object of the required type.. `scenarioSchema.CinemaUnits.AddRange(CinemaUnitSchemas.Select(x => new CinemaUnit(){ Name=x.Name, AttendantPoints=x.AttendantPoints.ToList(), ShowPoints=x.ShowPoints}));` ?

Comment: From the error it appears that one of the classes you have in your example is incorrect. The classes in your actual program do not have the same attributes. One has a `List<AttendantPoint> AttendantPoints`, and the other has a  `List<AttendantPointSchema> AttendantPoints`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually need it's a way to convert AttendantPoint to AttendantPointSchema.

**Solution 1**: You can use AutoMapper framework to do it.

**Solution 2**: You can write generic converter like @Eser suggested.

**Solution 3**: You can crate converter manually for each class using extension methods, implicit or explicit operators or just write helper class with static functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a Copy method that makes a shallow copy using reflection.

```
void Copy(object from, object to)
{
    var dict = to.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p);
    foreach(var p in from.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        dict[p.Name].SetValue(to, p.GetValue(from,null), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Eser. The method is giving me an error in p.GetValue() indicating that 'No overload method 'GetValue' takes 1 argument'.

Comment: @Codinghierarchy `p.GetValue(from,null)` I updated the answer

Comment: OP already doing this but manually(which is more performant then reading properties through reflection on every copy ;)). Main problem is that OP try assign collection of one type to another. And expects it should work when both types have properties with same name - which is not a case in the C#.

Comment: I confirm what Fabio just said. The suggested solution, although highly performance wise, it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but it is probably a good bet that it is.
You are using a `foreach` statement with the camel case `cinemaUnits` but when you are trying to copy the fields you are using  the title case `CinemaUnits` instead of the variable with camel case.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I just edited my question. I copied and pasted it the wrong way. That is not the error causing issue. However, thanks for bringing it up.